# In-House profile not listing under distribution certificate identity, showing under developer identity

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am creating provisioning profile for in-house distribution. In Apple developer portal first I created AppId, then I created Distribution Certificate, finally I created In-house provisioning profile with distribution certificate. After creating profile, I refreshed Xcode and my profile was listed in that. In Xamarin under iOS Bundle Signing tab, in-house provisioning profile is listing for developer identity, not for distribution certificate identity.

If I select Distribution (Automatic) identity, in-house profile is shown and if I choose my profile, its showing compile error as below:

`Error: No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS code signing keys`

I am able to build ipa without any error in developer identity, but it is actually in-house(distribution) profile. Since ipa is created under developer identity with in-house profile, while installing app on test device, I am getting error as below in some devices.

`Unable to download item. Please try again later`

What could be the problem, many times I recreated certificate & profile. I am creating & opening certificate in same Mac machine only.